# Query ran through JDBC returns zero results while PSQL returns correct amount

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm querying a View in PostgreSQL and am getting two different results between JDBC and the PSQL console. The PSQL console does contain the correct results.

Here is a contrived example of what is happening.

Imagine the view as follows:

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| org_id | integer |
| custom_attributes | jsonb |
| time_period | tstzrange |

and the query being executed is as follows:

```
SELECT
    t0.id
FROM
    profile_view t0
WHERE
    t0.time_period @> '2022-04-11 14:21:27.862453'::timestamptz
    AND t0.org_id = 270
    AND t0.custom_attributes IS NOT NULL;
```

Imagine the database has 119 records with custom attributes, and 567 records without custom attributes.

When executing this in PSQL, I will get 119 records, but when this is executed through JDBC I get no records. Logging was enabled through PostgreSQL and the queries executed were identical.

Two interesting things of note:

1. When I change the query to have `AND t0.custom_attributes IS NULL` I get back the expected 567 records in JDBC and PSQL.
2. When I remove the `t0.time_period @> '2022-04-11 14:21:27.862453'::timestamptz` I get expected 119 records in JDBC and PSQL.

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the problem is in the cast of the string literal to `timestamp with time zone`. The result of such a type cast will depend on the current setting of the parameter `TimeZone`.

I see two remedies:

1. make sure that `TimeZone` is always set to the same value, by explicitly setting it in your application
2. include a time zone offset in your string literal, e.g.

   ```
   '2022-04-11 14:21:27.862453+00'
   ```

Comment: I had tried setting the time zone and had no luck. Just tried adding the offset in the string and that didn't resolve it either. I figure, if this were the issue, why would the query behave as expected when the WHERE for t0.custom_attributes is changed from NOT NULL to NULL?

Comment: Well, mine was the only possible answer. If you are certain that that is not the problem, then you must be connecting to a different database, have a different `search_path` or a similarly trivial error. Or the query you are running via JDBC is actually different.

Comment: I appreciate your persistence, I took another stab at it and found I had used the incorrect time zone. Thank you! Do you have any thoughts on why it worked with the alternative WHERE?

Comment: Coincidence? The time period might contain both timestamps.